# Writing Circle Area in ECLiPSe-CLP has Error

Tags: prolog

I write a predicate for calculating Circle Area by EClipse-clp.

```
 circle(R) :- S is 3.14*R^2, write(S).
```

it has following Error:

calling an undefined procedure circle(R) :- S is 3.14 * R^2, write(S) in module eclipse

Comment: There is nothing specific to this system. Your question applies to any Prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really very basic.  You have to distinguish

- **Definitions** - this is your program code, consisting of *predicate definitions*, which in turn are made up of *facts* and *rules*.  Logically, this is where you define what is *true*.
- **Queries** - this is where you call your program. Logically, you ask whether something is *true*, and how.

Definitions are usually loaded/compiled from a source file. Queries are usually typed into the query prompt.  You seem to be typing a definition into the query prompt.

Comment: My query was : circle(6).